# Inside a List Tree - Target only the elements inside the first level LI childrens

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href='#'>Nav1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Nav2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Nav3</a></li>
    <li><a href='h#'>Nav4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I only want to target the anchor tag with text `Nav1`. Here's the CSS I am using that isn't working. It is selecting both `Nav1` and `Sub1`.

```
.nav li:first-child > a {

}
```

Should I just use a class or is there a way to do it without one?

Comment: why don't you just use .nav a, then override those styles with .nav ul a?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get just the very next li only using another child selector [`>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) between `.nav` and `li:first-child`

```
.nav > li:first-child > a {

}
```